# Possessive "‘s" or "of", or neither?

Tags: possessives

When can you swap the words and remove "of" like "the cafe of the uni" vs "the uni cafe"?
Which one is more natural for everyday English?

- the cafe of the uni
- the uni cafe
- the uni's cafe

This is an example only and I'm looking for a general answer.
Noun1 + of + noun 2 vs noun2 + noun 1

Comment: There is no general answer to this. There are many instances and not all can be "swapped out". You just have to go along and accept them. For example: we say the man of the hour, but not the hour man. There are too many and English is very irregular as a whole. We say: the door of the car, and the car door. And it all depends on context.

Comment: Could you edit the title, which says possessive "'s"? The main body talks about the "of" form and the attributive noun form.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/157380/9161, https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/148605/9161

Answer (score 2):

Colloquially, "uni cafe" is preferred.

However, if there were a conversation, such as,

"Do you prefer the cafe at the hospital or the university?"

"The cafe of the uni!" *could* be an answer (unless the hospital served better food), emphasizing the choice by the phrasing.

*Caveat:* [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=school%20cafeteria%2Ccafeteria%20of%20the%20school&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) finds the phrase with the preposition almost nonexistent. ("uni cafe" was not found, so "school cafeteria" was substituted) .

Comment: Many UK English speakers really hate the use of 'uni' for 'university'.

Comment: That's the legacy of ["Education, education, education!"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+to+uni%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cwent+to+uni%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1990&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Apparently BrE accounts for 75% of all written instances of even the non-contracted form [went to university.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+to+university%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cwent+to+university%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1990&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Americans either don't go to uni, or they describe it differently.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I suppose when I wrote 'Many UK English speakers', I meant 'I', who went to Poly.

Comment: You and me both, mate! But once-downmarket Portsmouth Poly is now [a top 3 modern university for research power.](https://www.port.ac.uk/) Whatever exactly "research power" means.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - sounds like a bathroom cleaner.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little bit. Unit cafe was just an example, I'm looking for a general guideline. Noun1 + of + noun 2 vs noun2 + noun 1

Comment: @RealDreams, in many cases, both are acceptable, though the shorter seems to be preferred. E.G., "human heart" vs. "heart of a human", "a winter day" vs. "a day **in** winter", "Ferrari Daytona" vs. "Daytona **by** Ferrari". Use NGRAM if you have a specific question.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik are there instances that only "of"-form is acceptable? e.g. "the leg of the table"?

Comment: There maybe cases where it's not acceptable, but nothing is wrong with "the table leg". One can say "The leg of the table is short," or "The table's leg is short," or "The table leg is short."

Answer (score 0):

A university might have more than one eating place attached to it, so let's consider 'library'. On campus, we would normally talk about **the University Library**, but (before I retired) I might have said to someone I met when away from home **"I work in the library of the University of Derby"**.

I don't think it's possible to formulate a general rule, but mostly we would use the shorter form when the context is obvious (to use Dr Moishe's example, **table leg** when sitting at a wonky table), and we would be more likely to use 'the X of the Y' when it's necessary to explain the situation. (**I'm looking for something to put under the leg of the table in my room, because it's shorter than the others.**)

Answer (score 0):

The most common phrasing would be neither. Usually, we would say "the uni's cafe".

"The Uni Cafe" could work as a business name. It can also be used in a sentence where it is interchangeable with an actual name.

> "How about we meet for lunch tomorrow at the uni cafe."

"The Cafe of the Uni" is weird because "uni" is colloquial and the use of "of" is more formal.

"The cafe of the university" puts a bit more emphasis on "the cafe". It is a bit like saying...

> "The university's *cafe*, on the other hand, is an independently owned and operated business."

... but without italicizing "cafe".

> "The cafe of the university, on the other hand, is an independently owned and operated business."

This sentence structure is also useful when you want to decorate "the university" with lots of adjectives.

For example...

> "The cafe of the Frank Lloyd Wright Metropolitan University of Neoliberal Modern Architecture features tensegrity inspired furniture."

Comment: Thanks, could you generalise your answer, it's currently highly around the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Noun1 + of Noun2
or

(2) Noun2 + Noun1 (the attributive noun form, not the possessive 's form mentioned in OP's title)

For simplicity,  I will use the 2 numbers in my descriptions below.

I prefer (2) for its conciseness if Noun2 is not too long.  For a long Noun2, the Noun2 + Noun1 phrase becomes unclear; readers will start to wonder where the actual noun is.  Using (1) would improve the sentence in such a situation.

[Thoughtco Usage Guideline: Multiple Attributive Nouns](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012)  further explains
this problem caused by *noun clusters* and gives an example:

> FAX TRANSMISSION NETWORK ACCESS COST OPTIMIZATION PROPOSAL

> The problem arises when a whole slew of nouns are crammed together. The poor reader's brain has no way to decode this mess until he or she has already gone through it once.

That *FAX* example to me may not be so bad if the long attributive noun is in the title as readers should still be able to find the actual noun quite easily.  However, if the long string is not in the title (as a warning) and appears suddenly, surrounded by more words in the document body, it would affect the readability.

To answer your questions on when we can use (2), and when only the (1) is acceptable, I would say there are no fixed rules against using (2).  Thoughtco says

> it has always been legal in English to use one noun to modify another noun

and I extend the application to reasonable noun strings.

Normally, I would use this construction  if the particular Noun2 + Noun1 phrase is generally accepted and does not affect the rest of the sentence.  In the correctly phrased

> the leg of the table in my room

Noun2 has a post-modifier, and hence (2)

> the table leg in my room

would be less clear than (1).

For the *cafe* question, my preference is *the university cafe*.